# Expectation of amount of objects lying in a row such that object is chosen and its neighbours are not

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, proof-verification

> We have $n$ objects $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ lying in row. We choose $k$ of them. Let $X$ be amount of such objects $a_i$ that $a_i$ is chosen and its neighbours are not. What is the value of $E[X]$?

So, I tried to approach the problem the following way.

Let's call the object $a_i$ *well chosen*, if it is chosen and its neighbours are not. So $X$ is just the amount of well chosen objects. We can find the $E[X]$ the following way:

$$E[X] = E[\sum_{i=1}^n I_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[I_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n P(I_i)$$

Here $I_i$ is the indicator function showing if $a_i$ is well chosen.

Let's find $P(I_i)$ for $i = 2, 3, ..., n-1$ (for those $a_i$ that has two neighbours). For this we define the event $A_i =$ {$a_i$ is chosen *(not necessarily well chosen)*}. So we have:

$$P(I_i) = P(A_i \cap \overline{A}_{i-1} \cap \overline{A}_{i+1}) = P(A_{i+1}\ |\ A_i \cap \overline{A}_{i-1})\cdot P(\overline{A}_{i-1}\ |\ A_i) \cdot P(A_i) = \\ = \frac{(m-2) - (k-1)}{m-2} \cdot \frac{(m-1) - (k-1)}{m-1} \cdot \frac{k}{m}$$

For $i = 1$ and $i =n$ (for $a_i$ with single neighbour) we similarly have:

$$P(I_i) = P(A_i \cap A_{i \pm 1}) = P(A_{i \pm 1}\ |\ A_i) \cdot P(A_i) = \frac{m-k}{m-1} \cdot \frac{k}{m}.$$

Gathering it all together:

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^m P(I_i) = (m-2) \cdot \frac{(m-2) - (k-1)}{m-2} \cdot \frac{(m-1) - (k-1)}{m-1} \cdot \frac{k}{m} + 2 \cdot \frac{m-k}{m-1} \cdot \frac{k}{m} = \\ = \frac{m-k}{m-1} \cdot \frac{k}{m} \cdot (m-k+1)$$

Is my solution correct? The answer seems rather bulky. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also argue that for $1<i<n$
$$P(I_i)=\frac{\binom{n-3}{k-1}}{\binom{n}k}$$
and for $i\in\{1,n\}$
$$P(I_i)=\frac{\binom{n-2}{k-1}}{\binom{n}k}.$$
The numerators are just the number of ways to pick $k-1$ objects
different from $a_i$ and its neighbours.